# Alternative to Dictionary for lookup

Tags: c#, collections, lookup-tables

I have requirement to build lookup table. I use Dictionary It's contain 45M long and 45M int . long as key and int as value . the size of collection is (45M*12) where long is 8 byte and int is 4 byte
The size about 515 Mbyte . But in fact the size of process is 1.3 Gbyte . The process contains only this  lookup table. 
Mat be, is there alternative to Dictionary ??

Thx

Comment: _size of process is 1.3 Gbyte_ : that is not a problem. Do not use TaskManager to measure memory usage.

Comment: Is the size of the process causing issues?  Are you getting OOM (out of memory) exceptions?

Comment: That's why we have databases. To look things up!!

Comment: @banging the lookup time against even an in-memory database would be several orders of magnitude slower than an in-process, in memory data structure.  For some applications (capital markets trading for example) that might be a meaningful difference in speed.  Not saying that is the case here, but a database isnt always the answer in these cases.

Comment: Are there any contraints on the range of values for you long keys that would allow them to be used directly as indexes into an array of your int values?

Comment: @hatchet It's impossible , the range is [1000 10^12]

Comment: A very quick tip: create your dictionary with a capacity like `new Dictionary<long,int>(50*1024*1024)` (45 + 5 margin). But you won't see much difference in TaskMgr.

Answer (score 3):

How much effort are you willing to spend?
You could use a

```
KeyValuePair<long,int>[] table = new KeyValuePair<long,int> [45 M];
```

then sort this on the first column (`long Key`) and use a binary search to find your values.

Comment: an improvement to this idea would be to define a struct containing a long and an int, and then make an array of that struct.

Comment: @hatchet - not a speed improvement, but yes it would be tidier. The Tuple just let me write a 1 line answer.

Comment: Was not thinking speed as much as space, since with Tuples, the array would be an array of objects, and then you would also have the space for the objects themselves (the long and int).

Comment: @hatchet - you're absolutely right, it should be a struct. Will edit.

Comment: @HenkHolterman- I think a good solution, since the OP has specified a range that does not utilize most of the upper bits of the long keys, would be to use your approach combined with the idea of my answer. Have the struct represent the key internally as an int and a byte or an int an a word, and have the struct implement its own GetHashCode(), and expose a property for getting a setting the long key (which it then converts to the internal representation with some bit fiddling).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a SortedList instead of a Dictionary which will be more memory efficient but may be marginally less CPU efficient, ignoring issues about measuring memory and why you need to load so much data in 1 go in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

Dictionaries have an underlying array that holds onto the data, but the size of the array *must* be larger than the number of items you have, this is where the lookup speed of a dictionary comes from.  In fact, the size of the underlying array should be quite a bit larger than the number of items (25+%).  Combine this with the fact that as you're adding items this underlying array is being de-allocated and recreated (to make it larger) you probably have a fair amount of memory ready to be garbage collected (meaning if you actually need more memory the GC will reclaim it, but since you currently have enough it's not bothering to).

Is this Dictionary consuming more memory than you can possibly allow it to, or are you just curious why it's more than you thought it would be?  There are other options available to you (other answers and comments have listed some) that will use less memory but also be slower.  Are you running into out of memory issues?

Answer (score 1):

if your range is limited to max long values of 10^12, then a problem in regards to space is that you must use longs because you only need a few bits more than an int can hold. If that's the case you could do something like this: 
Store your data in an array of 512 Dictionary

```
 var myData = new Dictionary<int,int>[512];
```

to reference the int associated with a long value (which I'll call "key" for this example), you would do the following:

```
myData[key & 511].Add((int) (key >> 9), intValue);
int result = myData[(int) (key & 511)][(int) (key >> 9)];
```

Just how many dictionaries you create and the number of bits used in the bit fiddling might need to be adjusted to fit the true contraints of your data. Using this approach would reduce your memory usage by about a third

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, assuming that the data is static: use two sorted arrays- one of long and one of int.  Make sure that item at index N in one is the value for the key at index N in the other.  Use [Array.BinarySearch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch.aspx) to find the key values that you are looking for.